# python, установка mock module object has no attribute version

Tags: python

Ставлю на сервер гит-морду [kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/). При выполнении `python setup.py develop`, как мне до этого посоветовала команда `paster make-config Kallithea my.ini` выдается сообщение об ошибке:

```
...
Processing dependencies for Kallithea==0.2.1
Searching for mock
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mock/
Best match: mock 1.1.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mock/mock-1.1.3.tar.gz#md5=6da0cb632ed5ba0201c922a3de8f86ab
Processing mock-1.1.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-YYvPQJ/mock-1.1.3/setup.cfg
Running mock-1.1.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-YYvPQJ/mock-1.1.3/egg-dist-tmp-GXIT18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 179, in <module>
    """,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 27, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 129, in install_for_development
    self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 713, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 618, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 862, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 874, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 630, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 660, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 856, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1137, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1122, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 69, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 120, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
```

Вот [ссылка](https://pythonhosted.org/Kallithea/setup.html) на инструкцию по установке, замечу, что решил ставить без virtualenv, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Решение простое: обходным способом установил *python-mock* пакетным менеджером *zypper* (*pip* у меня не работает через HTTP-прокси).

Comment: одно замечание: это не «обходной», а самый что ни на есть «прямой» путь.

Comment: ну как сказать? если я установил сторонним для этого установщика ПО?

Comment: то есть пакет **не** из репозитория? тогда я неверно вас понял: путь действительно «обходной».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пакет ставился с репозитория ОС а не с easy_install | pip репозитория, paster make-config Kallithea my.ini выполняет скрипт по закачке и установке пакетов, а так же создания конфигурационного файла приложения. в чем то была ошибка, не вдаваясь в подробности я обходным путем поставил нужный пакет с репозиторя ОС, при повторном запуске скрипт не стал загружать пакет с прописанного репа, так как нашел его на машине.

Comment: ну, значит я совсем потерял нить. а обратить внимание хотел лишь на тот момент, что установка программ «штатным» дистрибутивным пакетным менеджером — это «прямой» путь. а всякие там *pip-ы* и тому подобное — «кривой» путь превращения системы в «помойку».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin > путь превращения системы в «помойку»   где можно об этом почитать?